Fixing hardwood floors by screwing them down
I have 3 year-old engineered hardwood floors sitting on 65 year-old joists. A lot of sagging and squeaking. I have already braced with 2x4s along many, many joists.  Subfloor is only half inch. I can’t do or afford whole-floor replacement. I am considering sinking twin pairs of screws in these 9.5”-wide planks at about 2’ intervals. I’ll putty over the countersunk screws. Any problems with this? Will it fix the sponginess and squeaking? Will it cause the planks to warp or buckle with weather changes in Atlanta (hot summers, cold-ish winters)? The floors are above an unfinished basement garage.

Sounds like you have access under the floor. There is a way to do it with 2X material, screws and construction adhesive. Please don't run screws into the surface of the floor, it just seems bad.... The squeaks are most likely between the subfloor and the joists. Typically engineered  floors that wide are glued down, so the squeaks should not be from the new install

what is the oc spacing of the joists?  what height are the joists?  are they 2" or are they 1.5" wide?  i wouldn't screw the floor boards down.  do you have blocking between joists?

"I can’t do or afford whole-floor replacement" in terms of paying someone to do it?  Or in terms of materials to DIY a subfloor replacement?

There are squeak-fixing products which consist of screws with two sections of differently-pitched thread, designed to be driven into the wood, then snapped off just below the surface, hopefully leaving a minimal hole to be filled in or ignored. If you have no access to the underside of the floor, these may be worth considering.
If you can access the underside, the better solution is probably to drive shims in to eliminate the motion.
My own solution is simpler than either of these. I simply decided to accept that old houses have loose floorboards which may squeak, and that's okay. At this point, I don't notice them unless I am actively listening for them.

Handy if teens are in the house also.

If younger folks are in the house, get used to sleeping through thundering herds of elephants. Unless you are the type who want to confront them immediately when they come in late.
